# Is appropriate to use the advantage of The Overflow Blog article to get the Announcer badge?

Tags: discussion, blog, sharing

I have stumbled upon the [Best practices for writing code comments](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/07/05/best-practices-for-writing-code-comments) article. Regardless of the excellent and interesting content (thumbs up to the author), I find this piece of code in the article quite interesting:

(Navigate to **Rule 6: Provide links to the original source of copied code**)

> For example, consider this comment:
>
> ```
> /** Converts a Drawable to Bitmap. via https://stackoverflow.com/a/46018816/2219998. */
> ```
>
> Following the link to the answer reveals:
>
> - The author of the code is Tomáš Procházka, who is in the top 3% on Stack Overflow.
> - One commenter provides an optimization, already incorporated into the repo.
> - Another commenter suggests a way to avoid an edge case.

###### Why is it interesting?

The link format is what is generated from the `shared` button under each answer/question. Breaking it numbers down:

- The first part `46018816` refers to the answer itself (link w/o my user ID https://stackoverflow.com/a/46018816)
- The second part `2219998` refers to the user that generated the link (or somebody uses the link in favor of a different user). The favored one is the user **mcomella** https://stackoverflow.com/users/2219998

Note that the author of the article is **Ellen Spertus** with id `631051` (https://stackoverflow.com/users/631051).

###### Is it appropriate?

Assuming I understand the [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer) badge system correctly, the users don't match. I have the following questions:

- Is it appropriate to share a post in The Overflow Blog article to get the Announcer badge **for the author themselves**?
- Is it appropriate to share a post in The Overflow Blog article to get the Announcer badge **for somebody else**?
- Is it appropriate to share a post in The Overflow Blog article to get the Announcer badge **at all**?

###### Why it shouldn't be appropriate?

Why do I ask whether is it appropriate? Normally, I would normally not care but I find two reasons:

1. The Stack Overflow Blog article that is *advertised* right at the top right corner of, I guess, every Stack Overflow page.
2. As far as I understand, posting to The Overflow Blog is restricted only to the team members and nobody else.

This gives certain users a significant advantage which I believe is not fair.

[image]

###### Disclaimer

- The goal of this post is not to whine over a badge, but the principle.
- I don't blame namely the author of the article. It might have been not intentional.
- If the meaning of the link is actually different and it doesn't contribute to the Announcer badge, I deeply apologize. However, the question would still remain actual, though.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯¯ I don't think it really matters much. Because the badges don't matter much. Most likely the article author asked a coworker to find a link. The coworker clicked "Share" and copied the link as is.

Comment: While I agree the badges don't matter much, I believe the principle matters.

Comment: So, what's the principle here? You're asking "is it appropriate" and I fail to see how to answer this. Appropriate according to what? What's the worse that can happen if it's "inappropriate"?

Comment: I wonder why they didn't use the chance to explain what that second ID means when they already explain how to properly link to Q/A in a comment. This should be part of the blog, because that could be an unexpected reveal of private information (i.e. the connection from your SO account to the real person).

Comment: This gives me a fun idea, it seems that [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) only has one badge, I wonder if one shares a link using the community users id, would they get a badge :P

Comment: I don't quite see what is the problem here. As I understand it, the badge is meant precisely for this case: announcing content via blogs. Whether it's an SO blog or an external one doesn't seem relevant to me. The only somewhat debatable thing seems to be that the link is attributed to another user.

Answer (score 6):

> This gives certain users a significant advantage which I believe is not fair.

There is no *significant* advantage to *possibly* getting a badge.
Especially considering the fact the link isn't even clickable, it's formatted as code.
The reader would have to deliberately copy-paste the link to visit it.

Comment: And you think it's only a *coincidence* that [they recently announced a tool that makes it easier to copy-and-paste](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/)? *Hmmm*.

Comment: The link might be code formatted, but they obviously hoped a web-crawler would still follow it to easily farm badges. Perfect plan .... :D

Comment: IIRC there were reports on MSE for users getting the announcer badge for posts they had never seen before.

Comment: This badge (or badge count) could be crucial for getting a USD 200,000-per-year job (e.g., be part of an ***early-stage*** automatic HR filter - due to a very high number of applicants).

Comment: @PeterMortensen [Citation needed].

Comment: In all my years here, @PeterMortensen, I haven't even gotten a single interview from badges or rep. So... color me skeptical of this claim.

Comment: @CodyGray rep may be an indicator for a potential employer, but I think you need a pretty substantial amount of rep and visibility for that alone to make employers reach out. A single badge in either direction, especially when it's _just_ an announcer badge for a user with 79 rep (at the time of writing), I can't think of a single employer who'd care about that one badge (except for OP of the question, if they're in a position where they can do that obviously :p).

Comment: I don't advertise my involvement on SO to employers for fear of losing the job because I'm a social media junkie.