# Can the Community user get the link-sharing badges?

Tags: support, badges, community-user

I've been wondering if it's possible to give the Community user the Announcer (and related) badges, as [it currently doesn't have any of them](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=badges):

> Announcer: Share a link to a post later visited by 25 unique IP addresses
> Booster: Share a link to a post later visited by 300 unique IP addresses
> Publicist: Share a link to a post later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses

Note: There used to be a request here to participate in an experiment (with a list of share links with the Community user's ID). I have removed it, since it is no longer needed (See the answer post).

Comment: We think in a [similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409022/is-appropriate-to-use-the-advantage-of-the-overflow-blog-article-to-get-the-anno#comment853676_409022) fashion ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1?tab=profile) is not able to earn any badges.

As [stated on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322050/1099857) by the former "Architecture Lead for Stack Overflow" [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver?tab=profile):

> All badge queries exclude Community in an effort to treat robots as second class citizens so that they don't get any delusions of grandeur and remain in their place of servitude to our great cause. This is quite intentional.

> ...and I guess it's worth mentioning Community is attributed to *SO MUCH STUFF* it also just makes the SQL badge queries run faster by ignoring it.

---

The only exception being on Stack Overflow where [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1?tab=profile) has earned [exactly one badge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=badges). It is worth noting, however, this badge wasn't "earned" in the normal sense it was [inserted manually](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335765/15497888).